# Leisure and consumption maximization trouble

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, taxation, profit-maximization

[image]

Not really sure how to to b). For a) I have (wh + Y – τwh) which I'm sure is fairly simple. I've never dealt with a utility function this complicated before and really confused by the notation in which they give hours (w, 1-τ) and consumption (w, 1-τ, Y).

Comment: "[When posting a homework question, it is therefore essential that you demonstrate some evidence of having attempted to answer the question independently](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions)"

Answer (score 1):

1. On the complexity of the utility function: 
   This is a quasi-linear utility function, i.e.
   $$
   U(c,h) = c - v(h)
   $$
   where $v$ is a convex increasing function of $h$. This is one of the four basic utility function classes.
2. On the notation: 
   $
   h(w, 1- \tau)
   $
   denotes the optimal number of hours worked given the parameters wage ($w$) and tax rate ($\tau$). Similarly
   $
   c(w, 1- \tau, Y)
   $
   denotes optimal consumption given the same parameters and the exogenous income $Y$. The optimal number of hours worked is not affected by $Y$, because $U(c,h)$ is quasi-linear.